# How to pass arguments to an event listener in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, events, sqlalchemy, listener

I have created an instance of SQLAlchemy model (User):

```
from .models import User

user = User()
user.save() # db.session.commit()
```

...then I bind an event listener to that model:

```
from sqlalchemy import event
from .models import User

@event.listens_for(User, 'before_update')
def receive_before_update_user(mapper, connection, target):
  pass
```

**Q:** How can I pass any arguments to the `receive_before_update_user` method when I `save` the instance?

---

For example, I tried to add a static property to the instance, but got `AttributeError` instead (I think it isn't the finest idea, but I haven't another one yet):

```
user = User()
user.property = 'value'
user.save()

...

@event.listens_for(User, 'before_update')
def receive_before_update_user(mapper, connection, target):
  print(targer.property)
```

Thanks for any suggestions :)

Comment: `user.save() # db.session.commit()` is a terrible idea. A session could have a lot more going on, and in general it shouldn't be the model object's concern when a transaction commits. And please include the full traceback and a [mcve]. Your event handler also has a simple typo. Is that just in the example?

Comment: @IljaEverilä, thanks for the comment and advice (you explained both concerns clearly). The third code block in this issue is just an example to illustrate what I want to implement (in other words expected behavior). I think passing arguments through object is not the best idea but I don't have another one in my mind :( So I deside to ask someone like you :) I need only an idea or concept to do that.

Comment: @YuriiRabeshko any update on this? Did you find a way to achieve this?